# How to use fairseq's Megatron in r-text?

Tags: r, r-text

I am using R 4.1.2, reticulate 1.22 and text 0.9.50.

```
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("oscarkjell/text")
library(text)
temp <- textEmbed("Hello!", model="anton-l/megatron-11b")

# Here comes an error message with traceback information. 
# My guess is huggingface's internal error.
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
KeyError: 'megatron' 
9.
stop(structure(list(message = "KeyError: 'megatron'", call = py_call_impl(callable, 
dots$args, dots$keywords), cppstack = structure(list(file = "", 
line = -1L, stack = 
c("/usr/local/lib/R/library/reticulate/libs/reticulate.so
(Rcpp::exception::exception(char const*, bool)+0x74) [0xffff9c3a97c4]", 
"/usr/local/lib/R/library/reticulate/libs/reticulate.so
(Rcpp::stop(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> > const&)+0x28) [0xffff9c3a9838]",  ... 
8.
__getitem__ at configuration_auto.py#317
7.
from_pretrained at configuration_auto.py#600
6.
hgTransformerGetEmbedding at <string>#68
5.
hgTransformerGetEmbedding(text_strings = x[[i_variables]], model = model, 
layers = layers, return_tokens = return_tokens, device = device, 
tokenizer_parallelism = tokenizer_parallelism) 
4.
force(expr) 
3.
reticulate::py_capture_output(
hg_embeddings <- hgTransformerGetEmbedding(text_strings = x[[i_variables]], 
model = model, layers = layers, return_tokens = return_tokens, 
device = device, tokenizer_parallelism = tokenizer_parallelism), 
type = "stderr") 
2.
textEmbedLayersOutput(x, contexts = contexts, decontexts = decontexts, 
model = model, layers = layers, return_tokens = FALSE, device = device, 
print_python_warnings = print_python_warnings) 
1.
textEmbed("Hello!", model = "anton-l/megatron-11b")
```

The following is my environment:

R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) Platform: aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit) Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Matrix products: default BLAS:   /usr/local/lib/R/lib/libRblas.so LAPACK: /usr/local/lib/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:  [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8    LC_NUMERIC=C         [3] LC_TIME=C    LC_COLLATE=C         [5] LC_MONETARY=C       LC_MESSAGES=C        [7] LC_PAPER=C          LC_NAME=C            [9] LC_ADDRESS=C        LC_TELEPHONE=C      [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=C    LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     [5] datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:  [1] multilevel_2.7  MASS_7.3-54      [3] nlme_3.1-153    stylo_0.7.4      [5] magrittr_2.0.3  text_0.9.60      [7] forcats_0.5.1   stringr_1.4.0    [9] dplyr_1.0.9     purrr_0.3.4   [11] readr_2.1.1     tidyr_1.2.0     [13] tibble_3.1.6    ggplot2_3.3.5   [15] tidyverse_1.3.1 reticulate_1.22 [17] stringi_1.7.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] colorspace_2.0-3   ellipsis_0.3.2      [3] class_7.3-19       fs_1.5.2            [5] rstudioapi_0.13    proxy_0.4-26        [7] listenv_0.8.0      furrr_0.2.3         [9] dials_0.1.1        prodlim_2019.11.13 [11] fansi_1.0.3        lubridate_1.8.0    [13] xml2_1.3.3         codetools_0.2-18   [15] splines_4.1.2      knitr_1.37         [17] jsonlite_1.8.0     workflows_0.2.6    [19] pROC_1.18.0        broom_0.8.0        [21] cluster_2.1.2      dbplyr_2.1.1       [23] png_0.1-7          yardstick_0.0.9    [25] tune_0.2.0         compiler_4.1.2     [27] httr_1.4.2         backports_1.4.1    [29] fastmap_1.1.0      assertthat_0.2.1   [31] Matrix_1.3-4       cli_3.3.0          [33] tcltk2_1.2-11      htmltools_0.5.2    [35] tools_4.1.2        gtable_0.3.0       [37] glue_1.6.2         tinytex_0.36       [39] Rcpp_1.0.8.3       cellranger_1.1.0   [41] DiceDesign_1.9     vctrs_0.4.1        [43] ape_5.6-2          iterators_1.0.14   [45] parsnip_0.2.1      timeDate_3043.102  [47] xfun_0.30          gower_1.0.0        [49] globals_0.14.0     brio_1.1.3         [51] testthat_3.1.4     rvest_1.0.2        [53] lifecycle_1.0.1    future_1.25.0      [55] scales_1.2.0       ipred_0.9-12       [57] hms_1.1.1          parallel_4.1.2     [59] yaml_2.2.1         rpart_4.1-15       [61] foreach_1.5.2      e1071_1.7-9        [63] lhs_1.1.5          hardhat_0.2.0      [65] lava_1.6.10        rlang_1.0.2        [67] pkgconfig_2.0.3    evaluate_0.15      [69] rsample_0.1.1      lattice_0.20-45    [71] recipes_0.2.0      cowplot_1.1.1      [73] tidyselect_1.1.2   parallelly_1.31.1  [75] plyr_1.8.7         R6_2.5.1           [77] generics_0.1.2     DBI_1.1.2          [79] pillar_1.7.0       haven_2.4.3        [81] withr_2.5.0        overlapping_1.7    [83] survival_3.2-13    nnet_7.3-16        [85] future.apply_1.9.0 tsne_0.1-3.1       [87] modelr_0.1.8       crayon_1.5.1       [89] pamr_1.56.1        utf8_1.2.2         [91] rmarkdown_2.14     tzdb_0.2.0         [93] grid_4.1.2         readxl_1.3.1       [95] reprex_2.0.1       digest_0.6.29      [97] GPfit_1.0-8        munsell_0.5.0      [99] tcltk_4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

I have searched for this question online, though not having time to try these solutions.

Solution 1:
One github issue page mentioned a similar issue for model name not found. The page thought one could extend the autoconfig class in HuggingFace.

https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/model_doc/auto#extending-the-auto-classes

Solution 2:
Follow the steps mentioned by the author anton-l:
https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/10301